# How to move common initialization code to a single place if nullability checks are enabled?

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings, dry, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

C# 8 introduced [static checks for null reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) and I'm trying to introduce them to certain (small) parts of my existing code.

One problem I'm tackling is with a pattern of constructors I'm using quite frequently in my code. Consider the following (oversimplified) example:

```cs
#nullable enable

public class SomeClass
{
  public string SomeProperty {get; private set;}
  public string OtherProperty {get; private set;}

  private SomeClass(string prop1)
  {
    SomeProperty = prop1;
  }

  public SomeClass(string prop1, string prop2) : this(prop1)
  {
    OtherProperty = prop2;
  }

  public SomeClass(string prop1, int prop2) : this(prop1)
  {
    OtherProperty = prop2.ToString();
  }

  public override string ToString() =>
    $"({SomeProperty}, {OtherProperty})";
}

#nullable disable
```

The `private` constructor is there to handle common initialization code that has to be run no matter what. It is called by the two `public` constructors to avoid having to copy-paste code within them. (Yes, if common initialization code boils down to a single property, arguably it does not make sense to move it to a separate constructor—but, as I said, this is an oversimplified example).

Still, this code (of course) produces warnings about uninitialized non-nullable types, since the `private` constructor does not initialize `OtherProperty`.

Is there an alternative between using static `null` checks and not copy/pasting code in such situations? If not, how do I use static `null` checks while moving common initialization code to a single place?

Comment: Try to initialize like this: public string OtherProperty { get; private set; } = string.Empty;

Comment: @Codigo Does this not throw away all benefits of static null checks? I now have an invalid state that should never happen but if it happens it is silently ignored rather than throwing at runtime! How is it not even worse than without null checks?

Comment: If you need to initialize OtherProperty with null, you can do it either in the same way in the property definition or in the private constructor, after testing whether OtherProperty is string.Empty. The idea is that in the public constructors you always initialize the OtherProperty, so it should not matter that it was set to string.Empty in the beginning.

Comment: This is a good place for using the [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving). If you initialize your properties as `null!` that allows them to be _temporarily_ null during initialization, while letting the compiler know that they won't be `null` for callers (since you're taking care of that as part of construction).

Answer (score 0):

What about moving your common initialization code into a base class?

This way the compiler can be sure you will never instantiate `SomeClass` without `OtherProperty` being assigned a value **and** your common initialization code lives in a single location.

```
public class SomeBaseClass
{
    protected SomeBaseClass(string prop1)
    {
        SomeProperty = prop1;
    }

    public string SomeProperty { get; private set; }
}

public class SomeClass : SomeBaseClass
{
    public SomeClass(string prop1, string prop2) : base(prop1)
    {
        OtherProperty = prop2;
    }

    public SomeClass(string prop1, int prop2) : base(prop1)
    {
        OtherProperty = prop2.ToString();
    }

    public string OtherProperty { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString() =>
        $"({SomeProperty}, {OtherProperty})";
}
```